# how to make a select query to firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using angularfire.
I have my node in firebase /texts/ and it loos like that:

```
{ title: 'title', text: 'long text' }
```

In my service i want to get just the title because i want to show a list of the titles and i don't want to load the texts at this moment because usually are a very long texts.
My service looks like that:

```
var ref= new Firebase( FBURL+'/texts' );
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var text = sync.$asArray();

this.getTitle = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var titles = [];
    text.$loaded().then(function(data){
        lodash.forEach(data, function(item){
            titles.push({title: item.title});
        });
        deferred.resolve(titles);

    })
    .catch(function(err){
        $state.go('login');
        deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I have noticed that inside the variable text there are all the objects so i get everything included the text. What i want to to is just a select name from texts :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access Firebase through most of its APIs, it will always retrieve complete nodes. So you can not tell it to retrieve only a subset of the properties.

That means that if you really only want the titles, you'll have to model your data differently. Right now you have something like this:

```
posts
  -Jas73489342
    title: "how to make a select query using firebase"
    text: "...."
  -Jasa8324023
    title: "bicycling the grand canyon"
    text: "..."
```

Those -J things are the keys that Firebase generates when you call `push`.

In order to be able to retrieve just the titles, you'll need to make sure that there is a node that contains *just the titles*. So let's split up our `posts` into two separate nodes: `titles` and `texts`.

```
titles
  -Jas73489342: "how to make a select query using firebase"
  -Jasa8324023: "bicycling the grand canyon"
texts
  -Jas73489342: "...."
  -Jasa8324023: "..."
```

To add a new post to the above structure, you'd do something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL),
    titles = ref.child('titles'),
    texts = ref.child('texts'),
    item = { title: 'Petroglyphs in Albuquerqe', text: '...' };
var newItemRef = texts.push(item.text);
var key = newItemRef.key();
var newTitleRef = titles.child(key).set(item.title);
```

So we first add the text of the new post to the `texts` node and then use the same key to add the title under the `titles` node.

You could also leave the `posts` node as is, but **add** a `titles` node with just the titles. Either way you'll have a node that represents precisely what you want: a list of titles.